# Yii Application where to place external API classes

Tags: yii

In my Yii web application I would like to place some(more than 10) business classes related to e shopwindow client. please suggest which is the best place directory to place these API classes.

Answer (score 1):

[Inside `protected/vendors/`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration).

Comment: You may read the documentation regarding this topic here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration